# Complex Numbers Range of Values of Mod and Arg z

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the range of values of $|z|$ and $\arg (z)$ for $$|z-4-4i| = 2 \sqrt{2}.$$

I'm aware that you can solve this geometrically by drawing a circle on the argand diagram and finding out the information from there. I was curious if there is an algebraic method for solving the problem of finding the range of values for the modulus and argument (i.e. without needing to consider it in the argand plane)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that the equation is solved by
$$z=4+4i+2 \sqrt{2}(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))=4+2 \sqrt{2}\cos(t)
+i\left(4+2 \sqrt{2}\sin(t)\right)$$
with $t\in [0,2\pi)$. Hence
$$|z|^2=(4+2 \sqrt{2}\cos(t))^2
+(4+2 \sqrt{2}\sin(t))^2=40+16\sqrt{2}(\cos(t)+\sin(t))\\
=40+32\sin(t+\pi/4).$$
Hence
$$40-32\leq |z|^2\leq 40+32.$$
Can you take it from here?

As regards the argument consider the ratio
$$\tan(\arg(z))=\frac{\mbox{Im}(z)}{\mbox{Re}(z)}=\frac{4+2 \sqrt{2}\sin(t)}{4+2 \sqrt{2}\cos(t)}.$$
Finally you should find that the minimum argument is $\pi/12$. What is the maximum argument?

Comment: Do we find then when $40+ 32 \sin (t+ \pi /3) = 2$? How do we do the argument?

Comment: @frog1944 Note that $\sin(t+\pi/4)=\sin(t)\cos(\pi/4)+\cos(t)\sin(\pi/4)=(\sin(t)+\cos(t))/\sqrt{2}$. As regards the argument see my edited answer.

Comment: Ok, why is the equation solved by $z=4+4i+2 \sqrt{2}(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))=4+2 \sqrt{2}\cos(t)
+i\left(4+2 \sqrt{2}\sin(t)\right)$?

Comment: Because $|(z-4-4i) /(2 \sqrt{2})|=1$ and any complex number of modulus $1$ is given by $e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Understand most of it, how did you find that the minimum argument is $\pi / 12$? I understand that that is the minimum value of the function, but without graphing it, how can you determine it?

Comment: @frog1944 Consider the derivative of the ratio.The derivative is zero iff $1+2\sin(t+\pi/4)=0$, that is $\sin(t+\pi/4)=\sin(-\pi/6)$.

Comment: Where did you see a method such as the following? I've never seen it done this way before, and I was curious if there were other things that could be tackled in a different way such as the following.

Comment: @frog1944 I am sorry but i do not have any reference to suggest. BTW I think that my method is quite  standard.

Comment: That's fine, I was curious as I've only seen it done geometrically by considering the figures on an Argand diagram.

Answer (score 1):

By $|z+w|\geq|z|-|w|$ we have
$$2 \sqrt{2}=|z-(4+4i)| \geq |z|-|4+4i|=|z|-4 \sqrt{2}\color{red}{\implies}|z|\leq6 \sqrt{2}$$
$$2 \sqrt{2}=|z-(4+4i)| \geq |4+4i|-|z|=4 \sqrt{2}-|z|\color{red}{\implies}|z|\geq2 \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Cool! How do you do the argument part?

Comment: Unfortunately this way works only where the center of circle is of the form $z_0\pm iz_0$ that is lies on $y=\pm x$, in this case $\arg z=n\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.